# When can someone be fired for "just cause"?

Tags: termination, canada, terminology

Where I live (Canada), an employer is required to give one week notice or one week pay when they decide to fire someone, UNLESS it's with 'just cause' in which case employment and pay end immediately.

I had been working in a call center, and hung up on a customer who was being very rude, and the conversation was not constructive at all*. I thought this was allowed, as I know others do it, and no one told me not to, but I ended up getting fired for this. Before I was fired, I asked my manager where I could find more information about this policy, and she literally said she couldn't find any official source.

Does my conduct qualify as 'just cause'? From what I've read, 'just cause' is very context dependent, and if I break a term in my employment contract, this would count. But in my employment contract it doesn't say anything about hanging up on someone.

I still worked there for a few weeks after the incident with hanging up. Does cause require the employee gets fired on the same day the incident occurred?

*there were several reasons why I thought hanging up would be the best thing to do, but I won't get into them as they aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: What country are you in?  This may affect the answers you receive.

Comment: @Stephen Canada

Comment: This appears to be a legal question. You should consult someone who is qualified to give legal advice.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, it is. But legal questions about common workplace situations are explicitly on-topic here (as long as they are not a request for individual legal advice).

Comment: @sleske I guess, I was trying to suggest that OP should seek individual legal advice. In my opinion they need it.

Comment: Im not sure about the legalities, but I live in Canada and I don't know anyone who was every given notice before being fired (or gotten 1 week's pay).

Comment: @SaggingRufus that's surprising. Here are the laws for BC requiring the employer to pay or give notice. https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/employment-business/employment-standards-advice/employment-standards/factsheets/termination-of-employment

Comment: neat ill have to check the laws for my province. It is entirely possible that those people didn't know their rights. Fortunately I have never been fired, so I have never had to look it up.

Comment: `I thought this was allowed, as I know others do it` first error never do what other do before confirming if it's actually allowed

Comment: I remember your previous question and I think others gave good advice to just leave it alone and accept your manager's response. It's not up to you on what is right or wrong for a company. It sounds like you went ahead and kept asking them questions about it and now got canned because of it. My advice now is to just leave it alone and start looking for another job.

Comment: @William-H-M a sure fire way to get on your boss's bad side is to ask them every question and pick nothing up for yourself.

Comment: @user62196 I'ts not the same to ask "Boss about when people is yelling me wih no reason and going nowhere, I see somes hung up is it allowed?" vs "Hey boss can I go to lucnh now? when is lunchtime btw? can I go to bathroom while on a call?" there's a BIG BIG difference

Comment: @Dan I seriously doubt I got fired for having asked what I should have done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Details will vary a lot depending on jurisdiction, type of employment and the employment contract, but the general idea is:

You can be **fired "for cause"** (also called "for just cause", "without notice period" or "summary dismissal") if you **violated your duty as an employee in a way that makes continued employment (even briefly) too much of a burden for your employer.**

Usually, simple mistakes (miscounting money, getting in a traffic accident in a company vehicle, forgetting an appointment etc.) are not sufficient. Instead, there need to be gross negligence or intention.

For example, in Germany, the term is *fristlose Kündigung* ("termination without notice period"), and it is commonly accepted by courts in cases such as:

- traffic accident while driving under influence
- physical assaults on colleagues or customers
- embezzlement of company money

The **consequences** of being fired for cause also vary, but usually you lose some rights that you would otherwise enjoy, such as

- severance fee
- continuing pay during the notice period

Also, you may be required to tell future employers (at least when asked) that you were fired for cause, which may make it hard to find a new job.

---

Whether that applies in the situation you describe is hard to tell without more specifics. If you had been given explicit instructions like "never hang up on a customer, instead just wait until they stop swearing", then possibly yes. Absent such instructions, I don't think there is sufficient reason for a firing for cause, but ultimately that is for a court to decide.

Monster.com has an article with details: 
[What It Means In Canada to Get Fired For Cause](https://www.monster.ca/career-advice/article/getting-fired-for-cause-from-work).

Comment: @dashofpepper: I added a brief explanation of the consequences of being fired for cause. Also read the linked article, it explains some details.

Comment: Having said that I worked at a uk call centre and we where told to warn them once that if they continued speaking like that you would terminate the call.

Comment: Also even in cases of gross misconduct the employer must go through the correct procedure to fire you ie have a hearing with an appeals process

Comment: Based on the OP's question, I can only speculate that he continually brought up the issue. That qualifies as a burden with the employer because they cannot continue business and must constantly revisit the issue when it was resolved weeks before. The OP is fixated on the hung up caller issue, when it sounds like the issue is lack of learning from that experience and cannot accept the disciplinary consequences of it.